# undefined local variable 'refresh_token'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, oauth-2.0, calendar

I'm trying to get my access token in OAuth2 so that I can access the Google Calendar API. Everywhere I look it says that i'm supposed to pass in a 'grant_type' that is equal to refresh_token but I keep getting the error

"undefined local variable or method `refresh_token' for # Did you mean? real_csrf_token"

So somewhere a long the line my 'refresh_token' is not being set. Please

**events_controller.rb**

```
auth = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
  access_type: 'offline',
   token_credential_uri: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
   client_id:            ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'],
   client_secret:        ENV['GOOGLE_SECRET_KEY'],
   grant_type:           refresh_token


 )

 auth.fetch_access_token!
```

Also, I have an omniauth initializer file, which is where I believe i'm missing my opportunity to grab the access token and refresh token.

**config/initializers/omniauth.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['GOOGLE_SECRET_KEY'],


  {
    scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'],
    skip_jwt: true
  }


end
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You posted only two line from your `events_controller`. In the first line `refresh_token` is used, but not defined. Where did you define `refresh_token` how do you pass it to the method in the controller? Btw: What documentation do you follow?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is telling you to pass a grant_type of `'refresh_token'`. That's a string.

Comment: But when I make it a string, I get the error: "Authorization failed. Server message: { "error" : "invalid_request", "error_description" : "Required parameter is missing: grant_type" }"